# When I set a variable to JTextArea it has not value

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I don't understand why a variable work in one part of code but in other part no. is the same variable, is referencied with the same value. this is my code

```
// Variables
String patologicos="";
String ginecologicos="";
String valuePanel="";

JTextArea ja;
```

here is built the constructor

```
public BaseHistorialPanelNoEditable(int typePanel){

        // constructor
    ja = new JTextArea();
    ja.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 280));
    setBackground(Layout.pac_background);
    ja.setEditable(false);
    this.add(ja);
    showInformation(typePanel);

}
```

Method to show some information

```
public void showInformation(int value){
                        // getting data from  DB
                getPatientData();

                switch (value) {

                case 1:
                    valuePanel = patologicos;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    valuePanel = ginecologicos;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                        // show message  
                Main.buildDialog(value + " " +valuePanel,  "Mensaje informativo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        // set a value to text area
                ja.setText(valuePanel);


        }
```

Method to get information from database

```
public void getPatientData(){

                    Main.readdb.select(
                            "select * from clinic where no_paciente=" +
                            Paciente.getPac_no());

                     if (Main.readdb.getNext()) {

                            patologicos = Main.readdb.getString("historia_clinic");
                            ginecologicos = Main.readdb.getString("gineco");

    }
```

this fragment of code show a message

```
Main.buildDialog(value + " " +valuePanel,  "Mensaje informativo",    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

using the same variable it works.

[image: varible working]

why when I use the same variable one line after, it doesn't have any value?

```
ja.setText(valuePanel);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is too much code here.  Write a little program that illustrates what you are doing, so that it illustrates your question.  Then post all of it.

Comment: "why when I use the same variable one line after, it doesn't have any value?" => after where?

Comment: Let's start at the basics: Do you call `showInformation` before `getPatientData`? Plus, have you considered using a `HashMap` instead of littering the code with private fields? It's a bit of a code smell

Comment: Ok, sorry. The problem basiclly is that the information of one variable is not set to a JTextArea, but if I try to print or somethig, it works well, has the correct information. I put the code to ilustrate. I have a Variable named valuePanel, depends of case it has a different value. The problem is when I set it to JTextArea has not value. If I do JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, valuePanel); Show the correct info, bu if I do ja.setText(valuePanel), doesn't work. Is not the Compenent becasuse if I set some dynamic vale it works and changes.

Comment: Do what @rcook said. Your problem is probably very simple, but you have to work to solve it. Show us a program with a string that you can display in a dialog but not in a text area.

Comment: Ok the problem could be very simple. I have 2 lines, one to display dialog, another one to set a text. I use the same variable, when I display de dialog works well, when try to use it in JTextArea doesn´t work. Is no prblem of JTextArea, I've tested setting a dynimc value, for example, the value of my switch-case, and it changes.

Comment: Line one. Display a dialog

      Main.buildDialog(value + " " +valuePanel,  "Mensaje informativo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

Comment: Line two set variable to JTextArea.

ja.setText(value+ " "+ valuePanel );

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but just an idea..

When you use setEditable(false).. It might be internal implementation that won't allow to set value..

try this:

```
ja.setEditable(true);
ja.setText(valuePanel);
ja.setEditable(false);
```

Hope this make sense..

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but is not the problem, I have set other value, for example, the value for 'case', and it is set correctly.

Comment: `setEditable` only affects user input. Changes by the program are not affected.

Comment: Yes, setEditable only applies for GUI, but you can set any text from Java code.